# What's wrong with this injection in my Angular controller?

Tags: angularjs

I have a controller called UserCtrl and it depends on a service called UserService. When the view that uses the controller UserCtrl loads I get an error:

Unknown provider: UserServiceProvider

Here is my service code:

```
angular.module('UserService', []).service('UserService', ['$rootScope', '$route', '$http', '$filter', function ($rootScope, $route, $http, $filter) {

    function loadType() {
        var deferred = $q.defer();
        $http.get('json/type.json').success(function (response) {
            var typeoflaw = response;
        }).error(function (status, data) {
            console.log("error trapped");
        });

        deferred.resolve(typeoflaw);
        return deferred.promise;
    };
}]);
```

Here is my controller code:

```
JBenchApp.controller('UserCtrl', ['$scope', '$routeParams', '$http', '$filter', 'UserService', 
  function ($scope, $routeParams, $http, $filter, UserService) {
          // Get the preferences information
      UserService.loadType()
      .then(function (lawtypes) {
          $scope.typeoflaw = lawtypes;
      });

      $scope.SavePreferences = function () {

      };

  }]);
```

What did I do wrong?

EDITED TO SHOW JBenchApp code:

```
var JBenchApp = angular.module('JBenchApp', [
    'ngRoute',
    'UserService'
]);
```

This brings to mind a question that has bugged me. What order do you declare your JS files for angular in the index.html page? Mine are currently:

```
<script src="../js/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="../js/angular-route.min.js"></script>
<script src="../js/app.js"></script>
<script src="../js/services.js"></script>
<script src="../js/controllers.js"></script>
<script src="../js/directives.js"></script>
```

Comment: have you injected `UserService` module in `JBenchApp` like `angular.module('JBenchApp', ['UserService', //other dependencies here ])`

Comment: Could be that `JBenchApp` module does not have UserService as dependency. But having the module and service name same, not sure if that will have any problems.

Comment: show you JBenchApp Module code .It seems UserService not registered in JBenchApp

Comment: Edited question to include JBenchApp Module code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be try this

```
 angular.module('UserService').controller('UserCtrl', ['$scope', '$routeParams', '$http', '$filter', 'UserService', 
  function ($scope, $routeParams, $http, $filter, UserService) {
   //controller code here
  }]);
```